# XNA how to check if the game window cross "X" is clicked

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Hi am making a game for Windows PC using XNA and I want to check when the game window  cross "X" is clicked, so I can instead draw a menu and do other stuff instead of the game closing.

So yea, how can I check when the cross is clicked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special needed for XNA, you can do this the same way as you could without it.

In your `Initialize` or `LoadContent` method need to find the Windows form reference your game is using, and add a `Closing` event to it.

```
Form form = Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle) as Form; 
form.FormClosing += OnClosing;
```

Then using this `OnClosing` method, you can cancel the close event, and run your own menu screen. (Probably by changing the game state and drawing something else)

```
void OnClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{ 
     e.Cancel = true; 
     ShowMenuScreen();
}
```